# Unable to connect my trailhead account with postman

Tags: trailhead, postman

I am using the url base url of my org to connect with postman ,which is https://curious-moose-190477-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com and getting the error. Please find the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a connected app in salesforce to authorize postman.  You need to ensure you add https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback to the callback URL list

Postman has built-in OAuth-base authorization. In Postman, click on the Authorization tab and select "OAuth 2.0".Click on Get New Access Token to launch the OAuth dialog. Use the following values:

```
Token Name: (Any friendly, descriptive name)
Auth URL: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
Access Token URL: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
Client ID: (the consumer key from your connected app)
Client Secret: (the consumer secret from your connected app)
Scope: (you can leave this empty)
Grant Type: Authorization Code
```

You can find details at [here](https://blog.mkorman.uk/using-postman-to-explore-salesforce-restful-web-services/)